# how to run a certain method in Spring boot using a button click in angularjs?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot

I have written my frontend using angularJS and backend using Spring Boot. I have the following class called optimizer, in which I have put the annotations as @GetMapping and I need to run this using a button in AngularJS.

Here is my Spring Boot code:

```
    @GetMapping(value="/optimize",  produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public void optimize() {
            List<Location> locationList = new ArrayList<>();
            Iterable<Location> location = repository.findAll();
            location.forEach(locationList::add);
```

I need to run this optimize using a button click in the front end.
I have created a button in the AngularJS like this:

```
<a routerLink="optimize" class="btn btn-danger" role="button" routerLinkActive="active">Optimize</a>
```

But it doesn't run the above optimize method.

Comment: First of all, have you debugged it and checked if it enters the function `optimize()`?

Comment: Yes it doesn't go inside the optimize().

Comment: I assume you've tried adding `/optimize` to your URL

Comment: Yes. Any suggestions for make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think by default your backend runs on port 8080 and your angular frontend runs on 4200. You need to write correct logic on frontend side which will make http request to backend.

Take a look in [this](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/12/04/basic-crud-angular-and-spring-boot) tutorial.

Comment: I have already done previously using this code.{
    "/": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false
    }
}